# access to the name of decorator by the decoree

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators

I am decorating a function `foo` with a_`decorator`

```
@a_decorator(params)
def foo(x):
#    print('Called',decorator_name)
#    other magic
```

Is there a way to access the name `a_decorator` inside `foo` so that I can print

> 'Called a_decorator'

```
def a_decorator(some_function):
    def wrapper():
        some_function()
        return some_val
    return wrapper
```

Comment: How is `a_decorator` defined?

Comment: In general, no. Doing so would require a lot of explicit namespace wrangling by the decorator itself.

Comment: can be an answer for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done by attaching decorator name to wrapper function:

```
from functools import wraps

def a_decorator(fn):
    @wraps(fn)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        val = fn(*args, **kwargs)
        # some action
        return val

    wrapper.decorated_by = a_decorator
    return wrapper

@a_decorator
def foo(x):
    print(x, foo.decorated_by.__name__)

foo('test')  # prints: test a_decorator
```

Function in python are first class and you can treat them as an object, attach attributes, etc.

Comment: great thanks.  should it not be   wrapper.decorated_by = a_decorator.__name__ ?